# Is it easy to develop a simple Firefox plugin (JS injection)

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, xul

So I was just wondering if it was easy to develop a very simple Firefox plugin where you could click a button, and it would execute some Javascript code!

Please note that I have never developed any kind of plugin for firefox, I just want to know if that is an easy task to do (like less than an hour)

I would also like to redistribute this very simple plugin to my friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do this, you could create a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/748/) [plugin](http://userscripts.org) instead. This is really simple.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to redistribute it with Greasemonkey?

Comment: You can publish Greasemonkey scripts on the web and other people can install them (if they also have GreaseMonkey). I think there is also a tool which can create stand-alone extensions from GM scripts but I can't seem it find it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Jetpack: https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/ or possibly GreaseMonkey: http://www.greasespot.net/

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you wanted to actually create an extension you could use something like:

http://www.rietta.com/firefox/Tutorial/overview.html

which provides a nice complete walkthrough. Couple with MDC, and AMO you have everything you need to build a Firefox extension. All you need a a background is some HTML, CSS and JavaScript knowledge and you're there!

Answer (score 0):

use  [crossrider](http://www.crossrider.com), their API's are so useful and simple